# How to program Emacs to syntax highlight html character references specified numerically

Tags: html, emacs, reference, syntax-highlighting, numeric

In html major mode, Emacs is programmed to syntax highlight html character entity references (i.e., character references specified by name, e.g., &nbsp;) but not, for some reason, *numeric* character references (e.g., &#160; or &#xa0). I guess this is a special case of the more general problem of customizing syntax highlight in a given mode. I imagine it involves some use of regexes. Can someone give me some guidance on how get started with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code snippet should help you:

```
(add-to-list 'sgml-font-lock-keywords-2 
   '("\\&#x?[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]*;?" . font-lock-variable-name-face))
```

but it should be put after loading of `sgml-mode` that provides `html-mode`. You can force loading with following command:

```
(require 'sgml-mode)
```

Comment: I like to wrap that kind of thing up in an `(eval-after-load "sgml-mode" '(progn ...))` so that loading needn't be forced.

Comment: I'm curious: what part of the code tells Emacs to highlight the numeric character references the same color as the named character references?

Comment: If any of the Emacs code maintainers are listening, I really think this should be incorporated into html mode.

Comment: the `font-lock-defaults` variable in the buffer is responsible for declaration of keywords for highlighting... But this mode is very old, maybe you'll better to look onto nxhtml-mode or something like

Comment: @sanityinc - yes, we can do delayed load, I simply prefer to load everything on start, because it's sometime hard to debug all this delayed loads...

Comment: @Alex: Yes, I used nxhtml-mode for a while. It was quite nice, but in the end I found it too buggy and went back to simple html-mode.